# System.Web.ApplicationServices not showing as a package option in MonoDevelop 2.4/Mono 2.8

Tags: mono

System.Web.ApplicationServices is not showing up in my package list when I try to add a reference to my mono 2.8 project. Any ideas why this would be missing?

**UPDATE**

Looking further into this, I found `System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll` inside my `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/` folder. So I guess it is installed and just isn't showing up as an option in MonoDevelop 2.4 for some reason.

**UPDATE 2**

Referencing the dll directly from `/usr/lib/mono/4.0/` does allow me to build the project successfully. However I still would like to know why this isn't showing up as a 'package' in MonoDevelop that I can reference and how I can fix it so that I am referencing this assembly the standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop keeps a hardcoded list of framework assemblies that are referencable via the Add Reference dialog (they look like packages, but aren't *really* packages). This is similar to what VS does, except VS uses the registry.

It's likely that the internal list just hasn't been updated to reflect the new assemblies that were added in 4.0, and that's why it doesn't show up as a reference. There's a bunch of assemblies this is true for (System.Numerics.dll is another I can think of off the top of my head.)

Update: Just FYI, the best way to get this fixed would be to file a bug at https://bugzilla.novell.com—that way, it can be tracked and followed up.

Comment: Thanks. I submitted a bug report. In case anyone cares to follow its progress, [here's the link](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=652835).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a pkg-config error.  You can manually add a reference to it by navigating to the path and selecting it.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it builds now, but I would still like to find out why it didn't show up as a package and how to fix that so that it is referenced 'correctly' in my project.

Answer (score 0):

While you are waiting for MonoDevelop to update their internal list of framework assemblies, you can add System.Web.ApplicationServices to the reference list yourself by making a pkg-config pc file - see [this blog post](http://www.thebinaryidiot.com/archives/2010/09/26/monodevelop-mysql-connector-reference/) for an example (or just look at the existing pc files)